# Заполнение таблицы через SQL запрос[JAVA]

Tags: java, sql

Привет, подключаюсь до БД вывожу данные через rs.next(), все ок. Написал функцию для вывода значений в таблицу и получаю каждый раз ошибку

> ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0

Понимаю что ошибка с индексом, но что только не изменял ничего не получается

```
public JTable getTable(String nameTbl){
    JTable tbl = new JTable();

    String querty = "select * from " + nameTbl;
    try {
        rs = st.executeQuery(querty);
        rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

        int countCol = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        int countRow = rs.getRow();

        javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel dtm = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel();
        dtm.setRowCount(0);

        int cC = 0;
        int cR = 0;
        int n = 0;
        String[] nameColumn = new String[10];

        int c = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++){
            nameColumn[c] = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
            c++;
        }

        while(rs.next()){
            dtm.setRowCount(dtm.getRowCount() + 1);
            if(cC < countCol){
                dtm.setValueAt(rs.getString(nameColumn[cC]), cC, cR);
                cC++;
            }
            if(cC == countCol) cC = 0;
            cR++;

        }
        tbl.setModel(dtm);

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       System.out.println("Error " + ex);
    }
    return tbl;
}
```

место возникновения ошибки

```
dtm.setValueAt(rs.getString(nameColumn[cC]), cC, cR);
```

Comment: Отделите мух от котлет, не нужно смешивать VIew (JTable) и DAO (DB), перепишите метод на получение списка ваших объектов, и используйте список для создания модели таблицы. Профит будет от ясности места возникновения ошибки, поддерживания и машабирования.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

посмотрите на сигнатуру метода `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.setValueAt`
вы кажется попутали cC и cR местами

а также вы нигде не задаете количество колонок `dtm.setColumnCount()`